# Comparing multiple string in one line (file) to single string in other file same line number

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, file, comparison

I am using python 3.8 for an application where problem is such that: I have two files

one is **actual_results.txt** file that consists of one string each line that is for example line 1 "Encryption Has Failed" Line 2 " Random Numbers generator passed" . . . Line N etc Then the second file is **expected_results** that will have multiple strings in each line which will represent possible outcomes of each test results e.g Line 1 "Encryption Has Failed, Encryption Passed, Data Corruption, False Key Used ..." Similarly, Line 2 "Random Numbers generator has failed, Random Numbers generator Passed, Data Corruption, ..." . . . Line N

Based on two files comparison between each lines a third file will be generated which will represent results on each line as: found or not found from expected results. What I have tried so far is as follows:

```
with open('actual_results.txt', 'r') as file1:
with open('expected_results.txt', 'r') as file2:
    same = set(file1).intersection(file2)


with open('final_output_file.txt', 'w') as file_out:
       for line in same:
           file_out.write(line)
```

This gives output based on full line comparison rather than comparing multiple strings in each line of one file(expected_results) to single string in each line of another file(actual_result.txt) .

Question is **How can I compare multiple comma separated strings in one file's lines to same line of the other file with one string?**

I have thought about a solution which i am not sure would work.

iterate through each line of one file with multiple strings to separate using

```
line.split(',')
```

to put into a list while comparing that list each item with single string on same line number on actual_results file.

Comment: Hi, it would help if you shared a sample of those files along with the expected result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are comparing every line of the first file to every line of the second file. What I think you want to do is compare each file line by line.

Something like this?

```
lines = []
with open('actual_results.txt') as actual, open('expected_results.txt') as expected:
  try:
    while True:
      a, e = next(actual), next(expected)
      if a in e.split(','):
        lines.append((a, e, True))
      else:
        lines.append((a, e, False))
  except StopIteration:
    pass

with open('final_output_file.txt', 'w') as output:
  for actual, expected, result in lines:
    if result:
      output.write('found\n')
    else:
      output.write('not found\n')
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to check if a string is one in a list, use an expression like this:

```
search_string in (list_of_candidates)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also try:

```
with open('actual_results.txt', 'r') as file1:
    actual = file1.readlines()

with open('expected_results.txt', 'r') as file2:
    expected = file2.readlines()

with open('final_output_file.txt', 'w') as file_out:
    for a, e in zip(actual, expected):
        file_out.write('found\n' if a.strip() in e.strip().split(', ') else 'not found\n')
```

Answer (score 0):

You maybe don't want to but you could use pandas to do the heavy lifting.

```
import pandas as pd

actuals = pd.read_csv('./actuals.csv', header=None)
expected = pd.read_csv('./expected.csv', header=None, delimiter='\n')

df = pd.concat([actuals, expected], axis=1, ignore_index=True)

df.apply(lambda row: True if row[0] in row[1].split(',') else False, axis=1)
```

Where actuals dataframe is:

```
        0
0  error1
1  error2
2  error3
```

The expected dataframe is:

```
                      0
0  error1,error4,error5
1  error2,error6,error7
2         error8,error9
```

The concatenated dataframe is:

```
        0                     1
0  error1  error1,error4,error5
1  error2  error2,error6,error7
2  error3         error8,error9
```

And the comparison yields:

```
0     True
1     True
2    False
```

---

My actuals.csv file contained:

```
error1
error2
error3
```

And my expected.csv file contained:

```
error1,error4,error5
error2,error6,error7
error8,error9
```